# Remove unwanted columns from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, formatting, output, row

I have two lists of CSV files that my program is combining into a single file.
The first group of files has 5 columns of data that I do not want to include in the output. How do I remove those 5 columns, whether I do it row-by-row or all at one time, from the data I have read in using `csv.reader`?

Here's my function (I would like to keep the function `def` and structure mostly the same):

```
def get_data(filename,rowlen,delimit=','):
    data = []
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        raw = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel', delimiter=delimit)
        if raw != None:
            for row in raw:
                if row[-1] == '':
                    row.pop()
                for i in range(len(row),rowlen):
                    row.append('-999')
                data.append(row)
    return data
```

I tried doing this:

```
raw = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel', delimiter=delimit)
    if raw != None:
        for row in raw:
            if rowlen == 13:  # This is true only for csv files I want to shorten
                row = row[0:8]
                rowlen = 8
            if row[-1] == '':
```

But the output file remained the same. Also, I tried commenting out `rowlen = 8`, but this just filled the columns I don't want with `-999`.

Comment: You should use SO indentation for your block code, add four space before each line of code and your code will show with syntax coloration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the row in raw or create a new list that will contains your sliced rows, here a correction of a part of your code with enumerate to keep track of the index of the row to be replaced in raw.

```
for i, row in enumerate(raw):
   if rowlen == 13:  # This is true only for csv files I want to shorten
       raw[i] = row[0:8]
       rowlen = 8
```

---

Another example where you don't alter raw :

```
new_container = []
for row in raw:
   if rowlen == 13:  # This is true only for csv files I want to shorten
       new_container.append(row[0:8])  # we just append your slice to the new_container each iteration
       rowlen = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It makes working with csv much much better..

```
from pandas import read_csv

def get_data(filename, rowlen, delimit=','):
    df = read_csv(filename, header=None, sep=delimit, usecols=range(rowlen))
    df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

get_data('input.csv',4)
```